# how to show lable in select drop down with [(ngModel)]

Tags: html, ionic-framework

In my code i am using select for drop down , but when i use [(ngModel)]
then it is not displaying label and if i remove [(ngModel)] then label is visible.

```
<ion-content>
    <select name="animalilist" [(ngModel)]="animal" >
        <option value="" disabled>
            <label for="animallist">Animal Type </label>
        </option>
        <optgroup label="Big Animal">
            <option value="buffalo">Buffalo</option>
            <option value="bull">Bull</option>
            <option value="cow">Cow</option>
            <option value="camel">Camel</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</ion-content>
```

if i remove ngmodel this is my o/p
[image]

and if  ngmodel is present then this is my o/p
[image]

Comment: You can use ion-select. : Please refer to, https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select

Comment: Typo btw, your name is "animalilist" and in the label you put it as "animallist".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Easy way to do is set ngModel to empty and use a default option like

```
set animal= ''

<ion-content>
<select name="animalilist" [(ngModel)]="animal" >
<option value="" disabled> <label for="animallist">Animal Type </label> </option>
  <optgroup label="Big Animal">
      <option value="buffalo">Buffalo</option>
      <option value="bull">Bull</option>
      <option value="cow">Cow</option>
      <option value="camel">Camel</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: why the triangle icon for dropdown is not coming?